# reloadData vs insertItemAtIndexPaths for CollectionViews

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have implemented the `scrollViewWillEndDragging` delegate method, so that I can add a new cell to the `myCollectionView` where currently  `myCollectionView` only shows one `collectionViewCell` at a time. If the user reaches the end, I want the user to scroll "into" the new cell, so as the user swipes left a new cell is created and the UI is centered on that new cell.

To do this I have implemented it in 2 ways

**The first way (using insertItemsAtIndexPaths) :**

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        // calculate the page, which is the current cell we are on
        if (page == dataSource.count) {

            // Update data source
            let placeholderFlashCardProxy = FlashCardProxy(phrase: nil, pronunciation: nil, definition: nil)
            dataSource.append(placeholderFlashCardProxy)

            // Update collection view controller
            let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: addedCards.count -1 , inSection: 0)
            myCollectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath])

        }
        print("Centering on new cell")
        // Center the cardCollectionView on the new page
        let newOffset = CGFloat(page * Int((cellWidth + cellPadding)))
        targetContentOffset.memory.x = newOffset

}
```

The problem with inserting a new item is that the UI isn't centered on the new cell when it is created.

**The second way (using reloadData)**

```
 func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
            // calculate the page, which is the current cell we are on
        if (page == dataSource.count) {

            // Update data source
            let placeholderFlashCardProxy = FlashCardProxy(phrase: nil, pronunciation: nil, definition: nil)
            dataSource.append(placeholderFlashCardProxy)

            // Update collection view controller
            myCollectionView.reloadData()

        }
        print("Centering on new cell")
        // Center the cardCollectionView on the new page
        let newOffset = CGFloat(page * Int((cellWidth + cellPadding)))
        targetContentOffset.memory.x = newOffset

}
```

Using the `reloadData()` method I the UI centers on the newly created cell although I have no idea why. I printed the offset for both methods and they are both the same, although using `insertItemsAtIndexPath` doesn't seem to center the UI on the newly created cell despite the offset being the same as using `reloadData()`. Could anyone tell me why this is happening? The reason I ask this is because I want to override the animation for adding a new `collectionViewCell`.